# How can I get rid of an Intellisense pop-up?

Tags: visual-studio, f#, intellisense

I am using `Visual Studio 2017`. It has nice pop-ups that display info on types and objects. But sometimes the information takes a large portion of the screen (e.g., for `Deedle Frame`). In those cases would like to press some key and get rid of the pop-up. I tried `Esc`. It works for a very short time and then the info pop-up reappears.

Is there a key that makes info pop-ups go away?

Alternatively, can one stop the display of such pop-ups and invoke them with a key combination?

(I tried to go to `Tools/Options/Text Editor/All Languages/`and change some settings (`Auto list members` and `Parameter information`) and that did not work. Similarly, `Tools/Options/Text Editor/F#/General` has the same settings but changing them does not help.)

Comment: Do you mean ‘Quick Info’ that descried in here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396? If so, go to Tools-Options-Editor and find the language like C/C++-- Advanced tab, under IntelliSense- Auto Quick Info and click the dropdown list and select ‘False’ save it. For different language, this option maybe under other tabs or have not this feature (like C#), navigate to https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/7197062-remove-the-default-quickinfo-popups-when-hovering and vote it.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT - Thanks. I voted. Not many options for F#, so I could not disable Quick Info. I guess I will have to learn to navigate the mouse cursor so as to avoid hovering over certain words.

Comment: @Soldalma TBH, you might have more success with filing an issue/enhancement request in the [Visual F# repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues) that's where the [nightly build of F# tools](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/14/announcing-nightly-releases-for-the-visual-f-tools/) comes from.

Comment: @s952163 - Thanks. Following your suggestion I did go there and reported the issue.

Comment: @Soldalma, after your reported this suggestion to the F# product team, could you please share the link in here as a reply, so other community members who have the same idea can easier search it and vote it, to know the progress, thanks.

Comment: @Soldalma Just another comment, when I hit `Esc` the tooltip disappears and doesn't appear again.

Comment: @s952163 - In my system that happens if you move the mouse cursor away from the keyword and then hit Esc. If the mouse cursor is still over the keyword the tooltip comes back almost immediately.

Comment: @Sara-MSFT - Here is the URL where I voted as you suggested: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/7197062-remove-the-default-quickinfo-popups-when-hovering

Comment: RE: the "Hit Esc to remove popup" thing.  If you are using a VI editor plugin, this also takes you out of insert mode - which is often when the popups occur and obscure what you're trying to type in the first place.